# How do I properly configure and use Gson?

Tags: java, json, gson

I'm making a game in Java Swing in which I have a big POJO for storing my game's runtime data such as sprite positions, current effect being displayed and so on. I want to be able to save it as a JSON to a file then reconstruct it from one later. I found Gson that supposedly does just this, but so far I haven't managed to get it to work. I always run into an issue where it fails to make some variable nested within my stored classes accessible.

Here's how I'm currently using Gson:

```java
public void loadGameState(String path) throws FileNotFoundException {
    gameStateData = gson.fromJson(new FileReader(path), gameStateData.getClass());
}

public void writeGameState(String path) throws IOException {
    gson.toJson(gameStateData, new FileWriter(path));
}
```

Here's the error message I'm getting currently when I try to use `writeGameState`:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" com.google.gson.JsonIOException: Failed making field 'java.util.Random#seed' accessible; either change its visibility or write a custom TypeAdapter for its declaring type
    at com.google.gson.internal.reflect.ReflectionHelper.makeAccessible(ReflectionHelper.java:22)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.getBoundFields(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:158)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.create(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:101)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter(Gson.java:501)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.createBoundField(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:116)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.getBoundFields(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:165)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.create(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:101)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter(Gson.java:501)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.createBoundField(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:116)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.getBoundFields(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:165)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.create(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:101)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter(Gson.java:501)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.create(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:53)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter(Gson.java:501)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.createBoundField(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:116)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.getBoundFields(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:165)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.create(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:101)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter(Gson.java:501)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:739)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:726)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:701)
    at gamestatedata.GameStateManager.writeGameState(GameStateManager.java:27)
    at rendering.MainWindow.actionPerformed(MainWindow.java:205)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1972)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2313)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:405)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:262)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:279)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6626)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3389)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6391)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2266)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:5001)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2324)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4833)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4948)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4575)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4516)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2310)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2780)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4833)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:773)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:722)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:716)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:97)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:746)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:744)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:743)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make field private final java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicLong java.util.Random.seed accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.util" to unnamed module @55129b54
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:354)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:297)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.checkCanSetAccessible(Field.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.setAccessible(Field.java:172)
    at com.google.gson.internal.reflect.ReflectionHelper.makeAccessible(ReflectionHelper.java:19)
    ... 57 more
```

`GameStateData` is the big POJO I mentioned at the beginning, it's about 300 lines long with like 30 variables and their getters, so I'm not sure if pasting that would help at all. All of the fields in my POJO are private, but I tried making them all protected or all public but it didn't help because some also contain fields that are private or protected so the same issue would still arise.

I'm using java 17.0.0 and Gson 2.9.0 as well as Maven. I think I'm using Maven to import Gson, but I'm honestly a bit confused as to how that works, but here is my pom.xml just to make sure:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>hu.elte.inf</groupId>
    <artifactId>ThesisMVN</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
</project>
```

From what I've read this can be be solved by moving Gson to the classpath, but I've done that but still running into this issue. Is there a step-by-step guide on how to make sure it works properly? Do alternative tools exist that still enable me to read and write JSON from a Java object effortlessly?

The issue lied within my POJO, me glossing over the error messages I got and my lack of knowledge regarding serialization and the transient keyword. My POJO had several images, that should all be transient anyway, the other source of my issue was a Random instance that couldn't be reached properly. TLDR: use the `transient` keyword and pay attention to error messages.

Comment: Try to pare it down to a small class that only has a few variables and still has the issue, and then put that class here. This is called a [mcve].

Comment: "I always run into an issue where it fails to make some variable nested within my stored classes accessible." Could edit your question and elaborate on this a bit more? Does `writeGameState()` create a JSON but when putting it back into `loadGameState()`, it does not work? Do you get an error? Or is `gameStateData` instantiated into an unexpected state? This seems to be the crux of your issue, but it is not elaborated upon.

Comment: @Flash103 I get the error when I try to use `writeGameState()`. At that point `gameStateData` is a valid instance with actual data in it.

Comment: @devor110 You should edit the question and include that information, including the actual error you're receiving.

Comment: Either you can access it or you can't serialize it, but maybe you can make some members just transient because they are not needed for the state?

Comment: @Turo yeah I think that's what I'll need to do. Before today I wasn't aware of how Serializable and the transient keyword worked and none of the guides I looked at mentioned this.

Answer (score 0):

Your POJO can just implement the `Serializable` interface and then you can easily write and read that class in/from a file with file streams. [You can find more about it here](https://www.baeldung.com/java-serialization)

Comment: Absolutely wrong in the context of Gson. The issue the OP is experiencing is that his/her class contains fields that cannot be represented in JSON at least out of box.